# In phonegap android app is it possible to make file downloaded to a particular folder

Tags: android, pdf, cordova, download

Is it possible that the user downloads a file from a website and it goes into the app root directory. I have the user download a pdf file from the website  and it should go directly in to a specific folder, so that the app has control over the downloaded files and not get scattered. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: you could download the pdf from within your app and then use an intent to launch it when it is finished.

Comment: Any idea how to download it from with in the app . If I use a plugin such as the phonegap downloader plugin but I have to give the url of the file. in future downloads the url might change with out the user knowing what the url might be.. Then how can we do about that. Thank for your reply.. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the app root directory is not writeable. You should either put it in

/data/data/{package name}

which is the private storage directory for your app or

/sdcard/Android/data/{package name}/files

which is the public storage directory for your app.

Comment: Simon any good books on phonegap.. Want to learn how to create apps in phonegap. Have read the docs but seeing in sample apps would give a better understanding to newbies like me..

Comment: This is probably the most up to date book. I have not read it but I did answer a few quesions for John. http://www.amazon.ca/PhoneGap-Essentials-Building-Cross-Platform-Mobile/dp/0321814290/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1345145792&sr=1-2 Other than that you can look at some sample projects that are open src. Ping me and I will dig up the links.